# Regex matches value from first underscore to last underscore

Tags: regex, perl

I have a regex which should match the string and keep values in `$1` `$2` and `$4`.

Below is the string:

```
Node=LTE03:File=/PMloc/dir22/XML/Network=ARX_ROOT_AO,Network=LTE,Network=Base,Manage=LTE,Element=LTE03/A20210115.1545+0530-1600+0530_Network=ARX_ROOT_AO,Network=LTE,Network=Base,Manage=LTE,Element=LTE03_file.xml.gz:Unit=U-3,Meter=1
```

I want following values:
`$1` => `Network=ARX_ROOT_AO,Network=LTE,Network=Base,Manage=LTE,Element=LTE03`
`$2` => `A20210115.1545+0530-1600+0530`
`$4` => `Unit=U-3`

Here is my expression:

```
File=([^_]+(?=_))_(\S+)_file.xml(.\S+)?:(\S+),
```

The above expression `$1` contains value from first underscore(`_`) to last underscore(`_`). Thus `$2` cannot able to have the time value as required. Only `$4` gives me proper value.

How can I have values as per the need which I mentioned above by using regex in Perl?

Comment: Why not 3 groups? `File=[^=]+/(\w+=[^/]+)/([^_]+)[^:]*file\.xml[^:]*:([^,]*)` https://regex101.com/r/LZdWPM/1

Comment: This appears to be a comma-separated string, with key/value pairs, why try to hack values from that using a regex? Why not split the string on comma and find the fields based on the field names.

Comment: @Thefourthbird 3 groups are also fine. But I already built the script which continues to have values in `$1` `$2` and `$4`.

Comment: @TLP actually this entire data I am getting splitting a paragraph with respect to `space`. So this data belongs to `$data[0]`.

Comment: @vkk05 It is ok to split more than once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could get 4 groups by using the negated character class for the `_` as well as for `/` and the `:` to not cross certain characters.

You can fine tune the pattern to add or exclude more characters between the matches.

```
File=[^=]+/(\w+=[^/]+)/([^_]+)[^:\s]*file\.xml(\.[^:\s]*):([^,\s]*)
```

**Explanation**

- `File=[^=]+/` Match `File=` followed by any char except `=` and match `/`
- `(\w+=[^/]+)` **Group 1**, match 1+ word chars followed by `=` and any char except `/`
- `/` Match literally
- `([^_]+)` **Group 2** match any char except `_`
- `[^:\s]*file\.xml` Match any char except `:` or a whitespace char, then match file.xml
- `(\.[^:\s]*)` **Group 3**, match a `.` and any char except a `:` or a whitspace char
- `:` Match literally
- `([^,\s]*)` **Group 4**, match any char except a whitspace char or a comma

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hSKkuq/1)